# finding all elements within a div that have a certain class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select all elements that have a class 'selected' within a parent div. It must be only elements in this div, as there are elements in the html that also have this class but we don't want to affect them.

```
<div id=1>
    <ul>
        <li class="list all">ALL</li>
        <li class="list selected">1</li>
        <li class="list">2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list">3</li>
        <li class="list selected">4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list selected">5</li>
        <li class="list selected">6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id=2>
    <ul>
        <li class="list all">ALL</li>
        <li class="list">1</li>
        <li class="list">2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list selected">3</li>
        <li class="list">4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="list">5</li>
        <li class="list selected">6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

so on click of class 'all', we want to remove the class 'selected' from all elements in the same div. This was as close as I got, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('.all').click(function(){
        $('.selected').each(function(){$(this).closest('div').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');});     
        $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```

I think my each loop might be wrong, I am not sure how to do each just within the containing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : Instead of filtering each `.selected`, you can get its parent `div` and then find all element with `class="selected"` to remove `selected` class.

```
$('.all').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('div').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');             
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQwmm/82/)**

Comment: Does find do the same as each? i.e. selects ALL the elements its trying to "find"?

Comment: Yes, find will select all element inside parent div with class="selected" and remove class selected from all found elements. see this http://jsfiddle.net/hQwmm/82/

Answer (score 0):

The `$('.selected')` code in your click isn't filtered by the parent.  What it does is find the `div` which is the parent of *every* `.selected` match and remove that class.  It's actually an easier solution:

```
$('.all').click(function() {
  $('.selected', $(this).closest('div')).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.all').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('div').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```